# How to update MongoDB with unknown object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using the following Mongoose model:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userID: { type: String, require: true, unique: true },
    username: { type: String },
    serverID: { type: String, require: true },
    roles: [String],
    gameProfile: {
        accountName: { type: String, default: '?' },
        accountLevel: { type: Number, min: 1, max: 65, default: 1 },
        accountClass: { type: String, default: '?' },
        favoriteWeapon: { type: String, default: '?' },
    },
}, { timestamps: true });

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

And I'm trying to create a "gameProfile" edit command, so the user can update their *accountName, accountClass, etc*.  Currently, when the user runs my edit command, I receive an object of the data they want to edit (all in one shot) that may look something like:
`{ accountName: 'bob', accountLevel: 55 }` or `{ accountName: 'billy', favoriteWeapon: 'axe', accountLevel: 100, accountClass: 'TANK'}` *or any permutation of those fields in the gameProfile object.*

So what I need to happen is basically merge that object into the existing User document, in one update. Without updating the values that weren't edited.

What I *naively* tried was this:

```
// const data = { accountLevel: 50, accountClass: 'DPS', favoriteWeapon: 'sword' }

UserModel.updateOne({ userID: interaction.user.id }, { data }, function(err, res) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
    } else {
        console.log('RESULT: ', res);
    }
});
```

Which doesn't error, but also doesn't update the database. If anyone can help me out it'd be much appreciated. I'm just learning MongoDB/NoSQL, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `findByIdAndUpdate` like this. As per the comment, I am updating it. You know what is coming in the data, take all the fields and then create a query and pass it to set.

```
const data = { accountLevel: 50, accountClass: 'DPS' },
      dataToUpdate = {};

Object.keys(data).forEach(el => {
    dataToUpdate[`gameProfile.${el}`] = data[el];
})

UserModel.findByIdAndUpdate(entityId, {$set: dataToUpdate}, function(err, doc) {
    if (err) console.error(err);
    console.log(doc);
});
```

Comment: The problem is that at runtime I don't know what values I need to set. I just know that I have a `data` object that contains the values that need to be updated. In your solution you are assuming I have 'accountName' & 'accountLevel' - but those may not exist in my data object

Comment: You should add this code to a function may be a query builder and get object which needs to be updated in the DB should be returned.